# How can I navigate to a specific category in angular?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, rest

I'm still learning Angular but I cannot figure this out. I'm building an Angular ecommerce app. The REST API that was built is kind of flat. The JSON looks like this:

`{
    "ShipFrom": "TN",
    "PartNumber": "ABC-xyz",
    "Category": "ACCESSORIES",
    "Description": "ABC Description",
    "Price": 13.98,
    "PictureURL": "example.com/xyz.jpg"
  },
  {
    "ShipFrom": "TN",
    "PartNumber": "EFG-xyz",
    "Category": "ACCESSORIES",
    "Description": "ABC Description",
    "Price": 13.98,
    "PictureURL": "example.com/xyz.jpg"
  },`

The actual call URL looks like this: 
`http://example.com/api/products/`

Is there any way to route to a specific category with this type of return?

Comment: you are using version 2?

Comment: you are asking how to call the api and return this json?

Comment: I'm on Angular 1.4.3.  I can call the API and return the JSON. I'm asking how can I return just products that have a specific category. Like an old fashioned query. So something like `http://example.com/category.html?category=abc`  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use route resolves for this. I'll advise to upgrade angular version or use ui-router since you're using Angular 1.4.X

Assuming your categories page should be shown on `http://example.com/category/{category}`, you setup a route (state) resolve to fetch the selected `{category}` from the json file and return it.

Read up on resolve [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve)

Comment: Thanks for that. What version would you recommend upgrading to? I'm trying to stay away from Angular 2 right now since I'm still learning Angular 1. Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: If you must use Angular 1, then Angular >= 1.5.X. Ideally 1.6